# Can we Upgrade samsung galaxy ace device OS form 2.3 to 4.0 or any other higher versions?

Tags: android

i am using samsung galaxy ace with 2.3.3 OS i want to upgrade my device OS to higher versions, is it possible?.if possible then tell me the procedure please...

Comment: This is not the right forum for this question.  Try "android" forum instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. 
Disclaimer: Do at own risk

Update Galaxy ACE S5830 to CyanogenMod 9

Step 1. Download the zip file for the ICS CM9 from here. Click Download. The file name should be the Samsung-Galaxy-Ace-ICS-CM9-Beta-8.zip file which was 125mb file size. Click Download and save it on your PC.

Step 2. Now connect the smartphone to your computer and then move the above firmware zip on the phone’s SDcard. Now disconnect the device from the PC and then proceed and power off the phone.

Step 3 Enter into recovery mode by pressing and holding the menu center button and power button together. In case it boots into normal mode, then you should repeat the action. Remember that this should be done when the phone is OFF.

Step 4 When Clockmod Recovery shows it main screen you need to select the option that says ‘install zip from sdcard’ and then ‘choose zip from sdcard’. Select the zip file you’ve moved at step 2 and then confirm the installation of the new firmware files.

Step 5 When the update is complete you need to get back to the main recovery menu and select ‘reboot system now’. Please note that your phone will perform its first boot with the new custom ROM. Also, this might take a while before loading all the apps and the Android ICS home screen.

However, in case the first boot take too long to load it means that something went wrong and you will need to repeat all the above steps.

That’s it, you have installed CyanogenMod 9 with Android 4.0.3 ICS on your Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830. If you have any problems on this rom comment here we will find solution for your problem.

Source:
http://techdraginfo.blogspot.com/2012/05/install-android-404-ics-update-on.htmlcream-sandwich/